Microsoft Graph (GraphServiceClient) does not return all columns in SharePoint Document Library
I am attempting to upgrade a C# project using the SharePoint CSOM library to use the Microsoft Graph API. Using the below code to query a SharePoint document library I get 37 "additionalData" properties.
string[] scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes);
var items = GraphClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[listId].Items.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "fields" };
}).Result.Value;

int count = items[0].Fields.AdditionalData.Count; //37

But in the older CSOM project using the below code I see 139 items:
ListItemCollection items = thislist.GetItems(query);
SharePoint.Load(items);
SharePoint.ExecuteQuery();

int count = items[0].FieldValues.Count; //139

I am not sure if it is helpful, but the names of the missing fields I care about are; "_dlc_DocId", "FileRef".

If you need specific fields to be returned, you can specify them in the inner select.  requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "fields($select=_dlc_DocId,FileRef)" }; At least try it whether it will work.

@user2250152 replacing my expands line with yours, throws the following error for me:
"Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Could not find a property named 'fields' on type 'microsoft.graph.list'."
I also tried an uppercase F in Fields incase the name of the variable was case-sensitive

Using a field that exists in the Graph response "Title" give the same error:
requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "fields($select=Title)" };
